# Nodejs Blocking code when using promises. Why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I'm learning nodejs and I need to process some intensive cpu computation. I've tried to do the following codes to learn about it:

**Worked**:

```js
const code1 = () => {
  return Promise.resolve().then(
    () => {
      console.log('Waiting...');

      let i = 0;
      while (i < 10000000000) { i++; }
      return 'Exited'
    }
  )
}
```

```js
const code2 = async () => {
  const resolve = await Promise.resolve();
  console.log('Waiting...');
  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10000000000) { i++; }
  return 'Exited';
}
```

**Didn't work**:

---

```js
async function code3() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Waiting...');

    let i = 0;
    while (i < 10000000000) { i++; }
    resolve('Exited');

  })
}
```

```js
async function code4() {
  console.log('Waiting...');

  let i = 0;
  while (i < 10000000000) { i++; }
  return 'Exited'
}
```

**Tests**:

```js
console.log('Script start');

// Execute "async" code. I've changed the code<number> to [1,2,3,4]
code1().then(console.log).catch(console.log);

const t = 3E3 * 3;
console.log('Do some stuff: 3+3 = ' + t)

console.log('End')
```

---

**Question***: I wanna know why the `code3` and `code4` didn't worked async. It blocked the main code until running the promise, for then, return the 'End' followed by 'Exited'

Comment: This isn't a great question for stack overflow. I suggest reading a resource such as https://rowanmanning.com/posts/javascript-for-beginners-async/

Comment: You're misunderstanding what `async` does.  Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function